# angular: enable button when asynchronous call returns

Tags: angular

probably an easy one: I got a button defined like this

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="reserve" [disabled]="buttonIsDisabled()"
```

where buttonIsDisabled is defined as

```
buttonIsDisabled() {
  return !(this.data_privacy && this.captcha.length > 0);
}
```

this.captcha is a string that is receiving its value through some async call.

In this setup the button is only enabled after the next click on the screen as the function is being reevaluated.
Is there a way to enable button once the value for this.captcha is set?

Comment: You can simply get rid of the method `buttonIsDisabled` and use the following in your template: `[disabled]="!(data_privacy && captcha.length > 0)"`

Comment: I tried, it does not work either unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean with "_ is receiving its value through some async call_"?
Can you provide a Example?

Comment: Together with the change from my comment above you may also have to explicitly invoke `ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges()` after `this.captcha` was received (see https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges).

Comment: if captcha  is a string then you don't need length property. just use !(this.data_privacy && this.captcha)

Comment: @vermilingua111222 are you sure that `this.data_privacy` is `true`? Remove it from the boolean expression temporarily to simplify the debugging process.

Comment: @uminder, u were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the angular change detection strategy must be on push in @component meta data. So, whenever any value gets updated in the component you need to run it using ChangeDetectorRef service

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
...
...
...
constructor(private ref:ChangeDetectorRef)
```

on ref instance you will get detectchanges();

Also, If you want to use angular default change detection

```
@Component({
    selector: 'newsletter',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, <--- change this to Default
    template: `...`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution @unminder pointed me to:

in our app component.ts import ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

then pass it to your component constructor, e.g. as cd and therafter run below method after u assigned value to this.captcha in your callback

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```